# C# WinUI TemplateStudio: how to prevent navigation during elaboration

Tags: c#, winui-3, windows-template-studio

In my app (C# + WinUI + Template Studio), I have an elaboration page and a left side Navigation Menu Items.

During the elaboration, I don't want that user can navigate to other pages.

What is the correct method to prevent this ?

I cannot find any example code to disable - temporarily - navigation.

I'm only capable to disable "back button" with:
`Frame.BackStack.Clear();`

I've tried to use App Service, like:
`App.GetService<NavigationViewItem>().SelectsOnInvoked = false;`
And also numerous variations, but without success, or looking for a "cancel event" when fired the:
`private void OnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)`
on "ShellViewModel", but cannot find it.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just disable the `NavigationView` like this.

**NavigationViewSerivice.cs**

```cs
private async Task DoElaboration()
{
    if (_navigationView is not null)
    {
        _navigationView.IsEnabled = false;
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        _navigationView.IsEnabled = true;
    }
}

private async void OnItemInvoked(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewItemInvokedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.IsSettingsInvoked)
    {
        _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(SettingsViewModel).FullName!);
    }
    else
    {
        await DoElaboration();

        var selectedItem = args.InvokedItemContainer as NavigationViewItem;

        if (selectedItem?.GetValue(NavigationHelper.NavigateToProperty) is string pageKey)
        {
            _navigationService.NavigateTo(pageKey);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Frankly, I was hoping there was a more orthodox solution. Is it wrong - as an alternative - to use a static boolean property (in "NavigationViewService.cs") and exit from "OnItemInvoked" when it's true (example, in my "Elaboration.cs": NavigationViewService.IsNavigationDisabled = true; await DoSomething(); NavigationViewService.IsNavigationDisabled = false;) ? Thanks for the answer (and also for your videos, they helped me a lot).

Comment: Thanks for watching my videos! Regarding to the alternative solution, First, I would try to avoid using static as flags at least. It's not a good practice in my opinion. Second, if you don't disable the ``NavigationView``, the user will be able to click items while ``DoElaboration()`` and ``OnItemInvoked()`` will be called while it shouldn't be. Third, disabling the ``NavigationView``, tell the user that "you can't navigate for the moment".